# Linux script: Reinterpret environment variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I am creating a Bash script which reads some other environment variables:

```
echo "Exporting configuration variables..."
while IFS="=" read -r k v; do
    key=$k
    value=$v

    if [[ ${#key} > 0 && ${#value} > 0 ]]; then
        export $key=$value
    fi
done < $HOME/myfile
```

and have the variable:

```
$a=$b/c/d/e
```

and want to call `$a` as in:

```
cp myOtherFile $a
```

The result for the destination folder for the copy is "$b/c/d/e", and an error is shown:

```
"$b/c/d/e" : No such file or directory
```

because it is interpreted literally as a folder path.

Can this path be reinterpreted before being used in the `cp` command?

Comment: The standard solution to this is `eval`, but the standard solution also comes with the caveat that using `eval` opens up all kinds of security implications and code maintainability hassles.  If you can, rethink your solution so it doesn't require `eval`.  See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818948/nested-shell-variables-without-using-eval for a discussion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use a variable's value as other variable's name in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714902/how-to-use-a-variables-value-as-other-variables-name-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `eval` to do this :

```
$ var=foo
$ x=var
$ eval $x=another_value
$ echo $var
another_value
```

I recommend you this doc before using `eval` : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

And a safer approach is to use `declare` instead of `eval`:

```
declare "$x=another_value"
```

Thanks to chepner 2 for the latest.

Comment: No need for `eval` in `bash` just to declare a variable. `declare "$x=value"` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want `$HOME/myfile` to support Bash notations, such as parameter-expansion. I think the best way to do that is to modify `$HOME/myfile` to be, in essence, a Bash script:

```
export a=$b/c/d/e
```

and use the `source` builtin to run it as part of the current Bash script:

```
source $HOME/myfile
... commands ...
cp myOtherFile "$a"
... commands ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
cp myOtherFile `echo $a`
```